# Is swimming pool water actually a weak topical medication?

Tags: microbiology, medicine, skin, infection, infectious-diseases

I was inspired by [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60912/why-doesnt-submersion-in-water-kill-fungi).

Given that the chlorine levels in swimming pool water are so high that they can [seriously harm amphibians](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/36887/38565), it seems logical that the water should also kill various microorganisms, fungi or skin parasites.

Is the swimming pool water a weak disinfectant? Are there any illnesses for which a doctor would prescribe a full-body bath in a swimming pool for this reason?

Comment: No, there are not. If a doctor wanted to treat a patient with dilute chlorine, they could have the patient put several drops of household bleach into a cup of water (or an ounce into a full bath) and soak in that. However, bleach damages skin as well (if you put your fingers in bleach, they feel slimy afterwards. That's dead skin cells that have been broken down by bleach.) So usually we don't disinfect humans (just materials) with bleach. There are less damaging disinfectants for skin and wounds.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Your comment is probably a sufficient answer for this question, so maybe you should post it as such so that I can answer.